# Best way to provide spacing between contents in a div without using margin/padding?

Tags: html, css

I want to have following layout:-

**Filter**: Filter1<---->Filter2<---->Filter3<----> ...

So currently I have implemented this using unordered lists and given padding right to each `li` element, but while writing media queries its difficult to give padding for each device.

Is there any way I can achieve this without using margin/padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex or you could make them all `display:inline;` and give the `<ul>` the styles:

```
text-align: justify;
-ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
```

Here is a demo showing what I mean using stretch for responsiveness:
http://jsfiddle.net/vevgnev9/